# Generating an image of multi character emoji using Pillow in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, emoji

I'm using Pillow to generate PNGs of emoji, using Google's [Noto Emoji font](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji?preview.text=%F0%9F%99%82%F0%9F%91%A9%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%91%A9%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%91%A7%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%91%A6&preview.text_type=custom) (which can be downloaded from that page). It works well for basic emojis but multi character emojis are output as, well, multiple characters. I can't work out if it's possible to output them as single emoji.

This code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

emoji = ""
image = Image.new("RGB", (600, 100), "#eeeeee")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("NotoEmoji-Bold.ttf", size=80)
draw.text((0, 0), emoji, font=font, fill="#000000")
image.save("emoji.png")
```

Outputs:

[image: A light grey background with a single black smiley face emoji]

Which is great.

But if I use a multi-character emoji, like a family:

```py
emoji = "‍‍‍"
```

then I get:

[image: A light grey background with four smiling characters on, two adults, a girl with pigtails and a boy with a backwards baseball cap]

Which is super cute, but I want the single-character family emoji:

[image: A light grey background with a single emoji showing four stick figures holding hands, two adults and two children]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install the [raqm](https://host-oman.github.io/libraqm/) library to get the multi-character emoji rendering correctly.

On Ubuntu that meant doing `apt-get install libraqm-dev`.

I thought I'd also have to specify it as the `layout_engine` for the font, i.e.:

```py
font = ImageFont.truetype("NotoEmoji-Bold.ttf", size=80, layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_RAQM)
```

But it worked even without doing that, once raqm was installed. But I left it specified anyway, to be explicit.

**UPDATE:** From Pillow [v10](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html) the `layout_engine` value needs to change:

```py
font = ImageFont.truetype("NotoEmoji-Bold.ttf", size=80, layout_engine=ImageFont.Layout.RAQM)
```